# Why is the text colour property called 'color'?

Tags: css, colors, properties

In CSS, why is it that the text colour is defined with `color` and not `text-color` or `font-color`?

Also, what's the difference between `font-` and `text-`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `color` property does not belong in the fonts or text categories of properties. It actually lives in its own section of the spec, both [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#color-and-background-properties) and [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html). There is even an entire [CSS3 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color) dedicated to color.

Each specification refers to `color` as defining the *foreground* color, then describes it as referring to the color of the element's text content. But since `foreground-color` would be unnecessarily verbose, the word "foreground" is left out of the property name. `background-color` is self-explanatory and serves as a distinction from `color`.

That said, while the `color` property typically affects the text of an element, if you also specify a border but don't specify a `border-color`, the border will take on the same color as the text. This is completely normal because it is stipulated [in the CSS box model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties):

> If an element's border color is not specified with a border property, user agents must use the value of the element's 'color' property as the computed value for the border color.

```
<div style="color: red; border: 1px dotted">
    This block has red text and a red 1-pixel dotted border.
    Notice only the width and style are specified in the style attribute.
</div>
```

[Martin Algesten in his answer has a nice summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296611/106224) of the difference between the font and text properties.

Answer (score 2):

*Font* is a variant of a *typeface*, i.e. `Arial` is the type face, `Arial Bold` is the font. You're not setting the font colour (I've never heard of a font that has a specific colour). You're setting the colour of the text.

I guess the idea would be that you can have a other elements that are affected by the `color`, not just text. Compare with `text-decoration: underline` would clearly just affect the text, but if we imagine we could insert a random shape inline, it would also be affected by the `color`.